# How to install Google maps for Android Automotive sdk_car_x86_64

Tags: android, android-automotive

I have built Android Automotive OS from the AOSP repository. I have built the following:

```
PLATFORM_VERSION=13
TARGET_PRODUCT=sdk_car_x86_64
BUILD_ID=TQ2A.230305.008.F1
```

Upon launching the emulator for this `sdk`, I get the following message:
`No maps application installed. Please contact your car manufacturer`.

I was wondering how to install the maps application and the necessary tools required to use it. I have tried looking around online but documentation seems to be scarce.

I have tried installing an [apk](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-23-04-13-release/google-play-services-23-04-13-190800-505809224-android-apk-download/download/?key=166cb978c269369bd5fb5f693ae21c9e90f493d9&forcebaseapk=true) via `abd` but didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you build Automotive OS from the AOSP repository Google map will not be available. But if you need to test something with google map in Automotive OS, you can setup automotive emulator from android studio it contains google map.

Comment: Is Android Studio the preferred method of testing then?